# Ionic 1: Cordova Clipboard copy value of an element

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using [Cordova Clipboard](https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard) in attempt to copy the contents of this h1 to the users clipboard on the click of a button. Unfortunately I can't make a JSFiddle, because it requires a device to work.

I'm console logging, and it's copying correctly etc. But when I try and get it from a value, it doesn't work? Does the plug-in allow this? Maybe the h1 should be changed or a directive created.

```
 <ion-content>
    <button ng-click="copyText('#copyme')">
Copy</button>
    <h1 id="copyme">{{example.label}}{{example.label1}}</h1>
  </ion-content>
```

In the controller:

```
  $scope.copyText = function(value) {
    $cordovaClipboard.copy(value).then(function() {
      console.log("Success!");
    }, function() {
      console.error("Error. Failed!");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out that you can put in `ng-click="copyText('{{example.label}}')"` and it'll work. However, this isn't the best solution for me, as I've got HTML tags inside...! May be useful for others :D

Let me know any other solutions!